# How can I parse XML file with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, rubygems, cucumber

I'm begginer in Ruby, and i'm learning to manipulate XML.

I have this sample document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
<nFE>
<infNFe versao="4.00" Id="NFe35181259275792000826550030011880971565816359">
    <ide>
        <CPF>4343232424343</CPF>
    </ide>
    <emit>
        <CNPJ>9538945893859</CNPJ>
    </emit>
</infNFe>
</nFE>
</nfeProc>
```

I coded this lines, to read the file and update the "CNPJ" node:

```
filename = "example.xml"
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(filename))
@doc.xpath("//emit//CNPJ").each do |node|
    node.content = "7669589859389"
end

File.write(filename, @doc)
```

The content method returns [], I can't find the node.

I tryed this same code in another XML, just with the "CNPJ" tag, and worked. I found the node and update the content, and save in the file.

How can I manipulate this XML file? I can't change the structure.

Answer (score 0):

just need littele change.

```
filename = "example.xml"
@doc = Nokogiri.XML(IO.read(filename))
@doc.at("//emit//CNPJ").content = "7669589859389"
# write the updated content 
File.open(filename, 'w') do |f|
    f.puts @doc
 end
```

Comment: This code didn't work on my project. It gives an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `content=' for nil:NilClass. How can I solve this? I put require 'nokogiri' in the rb file.

Comment: Can you check if `@doc` holds the xml content?